# MeteorJS user profile object property doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, web-applications, meteor

Hey guys I'm trying to make it so that the user profile of the default user package has the property of user.profile.friendList which is going to just be a quote unquote foreign key to the friendList collection where I store the user's friends. It's saying that the property friendList of undefined doesn't exist, though.

This is the serverside JS I have relating to it:

```
friends = new Mongo.Collection("friends");

Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
        // We're enforcing at least an empty profile object to avoid needing to check
        // for its existence later.
        user.profile = options.profile ? options.profile : {};
        friends.insert({owner:Meteor.userId()});
        user.profile.friendList = friends.findOne({owner:Meteor.userId()})._id;
        return user;
    });

Meteor.publish("friendsPub",  function(){
        list = this.userId.profile.friendList;
        if(list) return friends.findOne({owner:list});      
    });
```

and here is the client side js that interacts with it:

```
Template.login.helpers({
    getFriends: function(){
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            Meteor.subscribe("friendsPub"); 
            return friends.find().fetch();
        }
    },
```

and all that is supposed to do is create a user with a friends id as the property friendList of the user profile. Then it uses that to grab the users listed in the friends collection. I realize that it would only display the id of the users in the friendsList, but I wanted to get this up and running before I made it do the actual friends usernames.

Comment: Oh, it was null. That makes a lot of sense, now that I think about it. How would I access the user id in that way, then? Would I have to make a work around and call it the next time they do anything? That seems obnoxious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.userId` is `null` inside of [onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) (the account hasn't been created yet). One possibility is to examine the friend list inside of [onLogin](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin). Give something like this a try:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(data) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(data.user._id);
  if(_.isEmpty(user.profile.friendList)) {
    // insert stuff here
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could have the client call a method like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  addFriendsList: function() {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    if(_.isEmpty(user.profile.friendList)) {
      // insert stuff here
    }
  }
});
```

in the callback from [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser).

A third alternative is to just mark the user as "new" and sweep over all new users in a cron job. See [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/419) for more details.

Also note that `friendsPub` needs to return a cursor and not a document (you want your publishers to call `find` and not `findOne`).

Comment: is onLogin called after onCreateAccount? Probably a dumb question because you get logged in after creating an account, but I am not sure if the onLogin is different from the login function used when you create an account.

Comment: Yep - I just double checked and it is.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated by others the userId does not exist yet inside the onCreateUser. I suggest you take the email to add to a universal list or better yet, simply add the empty friendlist to the profile and fill that with other userId's. Below code is how you correctly add your attributes to the user profile.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    console.log(options.email); // possible available identifier

    var customProfile = new Object();
    customProfile.friendList= [];

    user.profile = customProfile;
    return user;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that publications should return a cursor, as what is documented in

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish.

The `friendsPub` publication returns a single document using `findOne`.  To quote:

> If a publish function does not return a cursor or array of cursors, it is assumed to be using the low-level added/changed/removed interface, and it must also call ready once the initial record set is complete.